# line break setting

Tags: line-breaking

Question:

My question is in 3rd question second line is starting from left side. I want to move it to slightly right side, exactly below the first line. How can i do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.60in, right=0.60in, top=0.60in, bottom=0.60in]{geometry}
%\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Question:~ Choose the correct alternative (Explanation is not necessary) }

\textbf{(1)}~ Body of first question

\qquad(A)~\hfill(B)~\hfill(C)~\hfill(D)~

\textbf{(2)}~ Body of second question

\qquad(A)~\hfill(B)~\hfill(C)~\hfill(D)~

\textbf{(3)}~ Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question

\qquad(A)~\hfill(B)~\hfill(C)~\hfill(D)~


\end{document}
```

Comment: @David Carlisle Happy to see you sir after long time.

Comment: Why don't you use a enumerate environment?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How can i do this in enumerate? Even how can i get the same result in my above codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this, based on `enumitem` and `tasks`(for the horizontal enumeration):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=0.60in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format =(tsk[A]), label-width=1.5em, item-indent=0pt, column-sep=1em}

%\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Question:~ Choose the correct alternative (Explanation is not necessary) }

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*), font=\bfseries, wide=0pt, widest=(9), labelsep=-2pt, leftmargin=*]
\item Body of first question

\begin{tasks}(4)
  \task
  \task
  \task
  \task
\end{tasks}

\item Body of second question

\begin{tasks}(4)
  \task
  \task
  \task
  \task
\end{tasks}

\item Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question

\begin{tasks}(4)
  \task
  \task
  \task
  \task
\end{tasks}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Use a list.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.60in, right=0.60in, top=0.60in, bottom=0.60in]{geometry}
%\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Question:~ Choose the correct alternative (Explanation is not necessary) }

\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries]
\item  Body of first question

\qquad(A)~\hfill(B)~\hfill(C)~\hfill(D)~

\item Body of second question

\qquad(A)~\hfill(B)~\hfill(C)~\hfill(D)~

\item Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question

\qquad(A)~\hfill(B)~\hfill(C)~\hfill(D)~

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for giving answer bu my question is do i have same out put from my mwe? I mean from my codes

Comment: No, your code gives what it it gives. If you want something different you have to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are writing an exam. This is a case for the `exam` document class, which can also provide useful features like automatic calculation of total points etc., so I recommend you check it out.

With the exam package, your code becomes:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam} %note the new document class
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.60in, right=0.60in, top=0.60in, bottom=0.60in]{geometry}
%\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{(\thechoice)} % brackets around choices
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\textbf{\arabic{question}}} % bold question numbers

\begin{document}
Choose the correct alternative (Explanation is not necessary) 
\begin{questions}

\question Body of first question

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice{}
\choice{}
\choice{}
\choice{}
\end{oneparchoices}

\question Body of second question

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice{}
\choice{}
\choice{}
\choice{}
\end{oneparchoices}

\question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question Body of third question 

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice{}
\choice{}
\choice{}
\choice{}
\end{oneparchoices}


\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

You probably want to actually add text to the choices. Check section 5 of the exam package documentation.

Comment: can i get it from my codes?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Do you mean if you can use this without installing something new? If yes, you should be able to just change the documentclass to exam in line 1 and do the rest of the changes.

Comment: Is it possible to produce same with my question codes by doing necessary changes.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the bold formatting of the numbers and the brackets around the options so that is looks the same as the rendering of your code. Is that what you wanted? If not, where do you see differences?